# Probability question, possible application of Bayes Rule?

Tags: probability

**Question::**

> You know that the probability it rains on any given day is 0.4. You are wondering if you
> should bring your umbrella with you today. You ask your friend if it’s raining right now and
> he says yes. Knowing that your friend may be lying to you with a probability of 0.2, what
> is the true probability that it is raining now?

It has been awhile for solving probability type problems. This seems like an application of Baye's but I am not exactly sure.

We have the following

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{rains on a given day}\right) = 0.4$$

and

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{friend lying} | \text{says it rained} \right) = 0.2$$

I am guessing we want to find

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{rains} | \text{friend telling the truth} \right)$$

Not exactly sure about this though I am little confused on whether this part is true

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{friend lying} | \text{says it rained} \right) = 0.2$$

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me, the answer should be just 0.8 if you know your friend always lies with probability 0.2. The additional information seems irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidP Wow, trick question then? That does make sense.

Comment: If you think of the extreme cases it might help make it clearer, say your friend never lies, it would be 1; if they always lied, it would be 0.

Comment: @DavidP I disagree.  See my answer.

Comment: Indeed, compare to the problem of asking the friend if they won the jackpot in the lottery.  That is such an unlikely outcome that even if they say they did you would be more inclined to think they are lying... or asking the friend if the pope is catholic.  If they say he is then you know they are telling the truth.  The problem absolutely depends on our understanding of how likely rain is.

Comment: @DavidP is correct here. The answer makes absolutely no sense at all.  If your friend claims it is raining, and the friend is lying, then how can it possibly be raining?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Actually, I misread the posted question, incorrectly interpreting the question to be asking what the probability is that it might be rain at some point today.  Upon reflection, I thing that you and David P are right.  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be the event it is raining.  Let $S$ be the event your friend says it is raining.  Let $L$ be the event your friend is lying.

Recognize that $S = (R\cap L^c)\cup (R^c\cap L)$, that is to say the friend will say it is raining either when it actually is raining and they are not lying or when it is not raining but they are lying.

You are asked for $\Pr(R\mid S)$, the probability that it is raining given that they said it is raining.

Recognize that $\Pr(S\mid R) = \Pr(L^c)$, that given it is raining they say it is raining is precisely what happens if they are not lying.

This expands by definition as $\Pr(R\mid S) = \frac{\Pr(R\cap S)}{\Pr(S)} = \frac{\Pr(R)\Pr(S\mid R)}{\Pr(R\cap L^c)+\Pr(R^c\cap L)} = \frac{0.4\cdot 0.8}{0.4\cdot 0.8 + 0.6\cdot 0.2} = \dfrac{8}{11}$

Comment: If your friend is lying about there being rain then how is it that it can be raining?

Comment: Upon reflection, I deleted my answer, and I agree with Suzu Hirose.  If the friend is lying, then it can not be raining at this moment.  The posted question is asking (in effect), is it raining at this exact moment?

Comment: @SuzuHirose We are told that our friend *says* it is raining.  We are not told that our friend is necessarily *lying* about it raining, though that is among the possibilities at play here.  Of course, if our friend *is* lying and says it was raining when it is not, then it is of course not currently raining.  Our friend could also be telling the truth and it actually is raining.  We have enough information here to be able to adjust our expectation on whether it is actively raining or not.  Since our friend is *usually* trustworthy, we are inclined to believe rain to be more likely.

Comment: Recognize the difference between $R\cap L$ and $R\cap S$

Comment: Well this is embarrassing.  I made two analytical fumbles on the same problem.  +1 (also) to your answer.

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer, the original comment I supported was wrong.